# How can I start and stop a GeForce Experience recording while in SteamVR?

Tags: nvidia-geforce-experience, steam-vr

Sometimes I'm playing a game in Steam with VR and I would like to start a recording of what I'm doing with GeForce Experience.

Is it possible to do this directly from SteamVR? In other words, without resorting to having to take the headset off and enter the start and stop recording keybinds in my keyboard.